/dev/kvm does not exist in ubuntu 22.04
I have installed kvm using
> sudo apt install qemu-kvm

However, it selects other package instead
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-kvm'

After installing, I check if /dev/kvm exists by
> sudo kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can be used

What could go wrong? The system is ubuntu 22.04.

What could go wrong with what? Please edit the question and add some details.

The solution is
sudo usermod -aG kvm $(whoami)

